# Having trouble rounding in c

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, floating-accuracy

While trying to figure out how to round a float like `1.255` to the nearest hundredth, I found something interesting. I'm using gcc 4.4.5 on Debian 6.

```
int   x = (1.255 * 100) + 0.5;   //  gives me back 125 instead of 126. 
float y = (1.255 * 100) + 0.5;   //  gives me back 126.000000.
```

Why is is that when I save to an `int` I get back `125` and not `126` ? In fedora when I save the above expression to an `int` I get back `126`. Is this a gcc bug in debian ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this looks like a "typical" floating-point question, it's more complicated than that.

This one involves a combination of 3 things:

- [The "usual" floating-point representation stuff.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- Implicit casting.
- Implicit type-promotion.

**Let's break this down:**

Floating-point literals are of type `double` by default. Hence `1.255` is of type `double`.

Thus the expression:

```
(1.255 * 100) + 0.5
```

is done using type `double`.

But because binary floating-point can't represent `1.255` exactly, the expression evaluates to:

```
(1.255 * 100) + 0.5 = 125.99999999999999000000
```

and is of type `double`.

Since this is less than `126`, storing it to an integer will result in `125`.
Storing it to `float` will round it to the nearest `float`, which results in `126`.

---

```
int    x = (1.255 * 100.) + 0.5;
float  y = (1.255 * 100.) + 0.5;
double z = (1.255 * 100.) + 0.5;

cout << fixed;
cout << x << endl;
cout << setprecision(20) << y << endl;
cout << setprecision(20) << z << endl;
```

Output:

```
125
126.00000000000000000000
125.99999999999999000000
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, interesting and I didn't know it ;)