# Rounding Error in Integer Assignment

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, rounding, scanf

How do you explain the Rounding happening here?I thought assigning float values to Int's always cause loss of value after decimal?

```
int z=39.99999999999999999999999;
printf("%d",z); // gives 40
```

Thanks

Comment: A bit heavy at points, but essential reading: http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have a double precise enough to hold all those 9s.

```
>>> '%.15f' % 39.9999999999999
'39.999999999999901'
>>> '%.15f' % 39.99999999999999
'39.999999999999993'
>>> '%.15f' % 39.999999999999999
'40.000000000000000'
```

Comment: Could you explain what you have written?

Comment: Basically, floating point can't represent exactly the numbers you write in decimal. You get its best estimate. In this case, he's demonstrating that adding the 15th 9 pushes the best estimate up to 40, so when you truncate it to an integer, you get 40.

Answer (score -1):

As you say: C's floating to integer conversion truncates (discards) the fractional part.

Which compiler are you using? I believe that that assignment is not being done at runtime, it may be a compiler issue.

Reference: [comp.lang.c FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/fp/round.html)

Comment: Floating point numbers are rounded. See Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  answer.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. May you, please, provide a link where that is explained? I am only able to find explanations like the one I linked. i.e. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694325/having-trouble-rounding-in-c[/link]

Comment: There is some interesting article which explains floating point numbers briefly: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point.html

Comment: Thanks. May I humbly ask you to try this, please? 'int a = 2.6;
    printf("%d\n",a);'

Comment: Because if it prints `2` it means that `2.6` is not being rounded, it's being truncated. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Read the article I linked. The compilator do following steps. 1) converts string 2.6 to floating point number. The number is rounded in this step. 2) Then it converts floating point number to int by truncating it.

Comment: Ok, now I see it! Thank you very much for your patience! :)